# Display Roles in nav bar of Webmatrix 2.0 app

Tags: web, webmatrix-2

I have a WebMatrix 2.0 app where I would like to have the user's Roles 
inside the navigation area of the _SiteLayout.cshtml page.

As an example of what I did elsewhere for deleting Roles, I have this:

```
@{
    PageData["Title"] = "Agma App: Users and Roles ";
    .
    .
    .
    // Errors
    var lstErrors = new List<string>();
    lstErrors.Clear();
    var result = "";


    //Code to remove a role(s)
    var deleteRoleNames = Request.Form.GetValues("deleteRoleName");
    if(deleteRoleNames != null){
        foreach(var r in deleteRoleNames)
        {
            try 
            {
                Roles.DeleteRole(r);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                @Html.ValidationMessage("deleteRoleName")
                lstErrors.Add("Role is not empty, it has users associated with it.");
                lstErrors.Add(ex.Message);
                result = "Role is not empty, it has users associated with it.";
            }
        }
        if(lstErrors.Count == 0){
        }
        else{
            PageData["errors"] = lstErrors;
        }
    }
}

<h1>@PageData["Title"]</h1>

    @Html.ValidationSummary()

<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Existing  Roles</legend>
        <ul class="roles">
            @foreach(var r in roles){
                <li>
                    <label for="deleteRoleName"><input type="checkbox" name="deleteRoleName"   value="@r "/> @r</label>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete Checked Roles" onclick="return confirm('Are you   sure you want delete the checked roles?');"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

This works fine.


Back to _SiteLayout  -- my <nav> area is currently compensating for my lack of knowledge by hard-    coded references to roles, i.e.:
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {
                            <li><a href="~/Administrator/Home">Administrator</a></li>
                        }
                        @if (User.IsInRole("BoardMember")) {
                            <li><a href="~/">BoardMember</a></li>
                        }
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

My question is, since _SiteLayout does not start with the @{} construct, I'm in a quandry about  how to accomplish what I want to do.